# Ordering a list of negative and positive numbers in R

Tags: r, ranking

I'm trying to order a list of negative and positive numbers in ascending order with values. For example, I would have numbers ranging from -3 to up to around 3.5. I have attempted to order them using the code below:

```
df1 <- df[order(df$"col1"),]
```

My result starts with -0.00, and then descends to -5. Then starts at +0.00, and grows to positive 4.00 ish. Meaning it isn't being ranked how I was expecting to be (going from -5 to 0 then to positive 4.

Is there a way to address this? Thanks!

Comment: What does `str(df)` return? Are your "numbers" really character strings?

Comment: Looks like they are characters "chr"

Comment: If you want to sort by numeric value, convert them to numbers with `as.numeric(df$col1)`.